# Encrypting communication between BLE receiver and iOS app

Tags: encryption, bluetooth, ibeacon

I currently have an app which controls a locking mechanism via a Bluetooth connection.  The issue I'm facing is how to encrypt the communication between my app and the BLE receiver found in the lock so that the locking action only responds to the app (eg no spoofing)

If anyone can detect it the signal, how can I prevent someone from mocking the same package and opening the lock?  Would this be a good use case for an asymmetric encryption solution?

Important note: The lock is opened and closed upon payment within the app --  my main concern is preventing those who have not paid from using the lock either by spoofing a package or other means

Comment: If anybody can download the app and unlock the device, then why do you need encryption at all?  In other words, how secure does it really need to be?  A detailed answer to this question is critical, because it controls how much work you should go to in order to secure this.

Comment: Hi David -- thank you for your response and great question.  To provide more context: people pay for the use of the container the lock is attached to within the app.  In other words, I want to prevent people who have not paid  from spoofing a package to open the lock and use it for free.  *Original question updated

Comment: If a user pays, should he only be able to open the lock once or will he be able to lock/unlock the lock an unlimited number of times?

Comment: Hi Emil -- an unlimited amount of times

Answer (score 1):

One thing you need to worry about besides interception is somebody decompiling the app and getting the keys to generate whatever encrypted code will do the unlocking.  One way around this is to use a server-side solution to generate the unlock code.

The app could pass a registration ID and a lock device transmitted timestamp over SSL to the server.  The server would then verify the registration ID, and if valid, return a limited time unlock code based on a hash of the timestamp and a shared secret between the server and the unlock device.  This way, nothing secret is stored in the app code, so decompiling it is not useful.  Also, because the unlock code is only valid for a few seconds, interception is not not useful either.

Comment: Hi David - thank you for the response!  Are there resources you could point me to that would help to explain this process in more detail?  I'm trying to wrap my head around this process: 1.) an SSL request is sent to a remote server from the iphone app 2.) The identity of the iphone app is authenticated through it's public key against the private key found in the server, 3.) A one time unlock code is sent back to the phone from the server, 4.) This unlock is validated against the private key found in the unlock device?